# Passing Boolean to method that expects boolean

Tags: java, boolean, wrapper, unboxing

I am passing a `Boolean` value to a method that has a `boolean` parameter.

When my value is `null` what happens? Will it assign a default value, like `false` to the argument in a method or will it cause any problems?

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: No, you will get a NullPointerException. So, don't.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes I did, whenever we checked it worked fine but for some people its crashing. So just wanted to confirm whether this could be the issue.

Comment: You can call it like this to be null safe`yourMethod(Boolean.TRUE.equals(yourBoolean))`

Comment: Java auto-unboxes the value by calling `yourBoolean.booleanValue()` and that statement crashes with a NPE.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz thanks for the answer. Looks like we are getting the Null issue but I am wondering why is it not happening for everyone.

Comment: Are they probably not passing null values? Because if they would, they should definitely getting NPE. Could also be, that in their case the exception is somehow caught and handled differently (or do you mean they use the exact same code and get different behaviour than you?). The whole question needs a bit more detail to answer properly.

Comment: @Lino and Zabuzard thanks a lot for the help. I have handled it in code

Comment: Many IDEs have an option to generate a warning about unboxing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unboxing

When you call a method that wants a `boolean` but give it a `Boolean`, Java has to **unbox** the value. This happens automatically and implicitly.

Therefore, during compilation, Java replaces your call

```
foo(value);
```

by

```
foo(value.booleanValue());
```

This process is explained in detail in [JLS, chapter 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - If `r` is a reference of type `Boolean`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.booleanValue()`

---

### Unboxing `null`

Now, when `value` is `null`, this statement obviously leads to a `NullPointerException` at runtime, since you are trying to call a method (`booleanValue`) on a variable that does not refer to any instance.

So your code crashes, it will not use any default value as fallback. Java was designed with *fail-fast* in mind.

---

### Get `false` instead

In case you want the method to receive `false` as fallback value, you have to code this explicitly yourself. For example by:

```
foo(value == null ? false : value);
```